# biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1] ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, opencv

```
contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]  #it does not contains any value...
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(biggest_contour)
cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
```

Results in an error of:

> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: The error is clear, no value in the `contour_sizes`. How did you `findContour()`. Can you provide a sample image?

Comment: I got it. Thanks buddy!

Comment: the same issue. please let me know how you got it.